# Initializing tables in light speed labeling equivalence construction

Tags: computer-vision, connected-components, labeling, binary-image

I'm trying to implement light speed labeling (in Matlab). In Algorithm 14 of this article, one uses a table ERA holding the equivalence between relative and absolute labels, and a table EQ holding equivalence classes. 
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ef31/7c257603004d818ca1e2a2aa67d36d40147e.pdf

Do theses matrices have to be initialized with some data? It seems to me that if EQ starts as a matrix of zeros then the ancestor a (line 14 and 17) will always be 0 and hence EQ will be an empty matrix in the end of segmentation.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Of course they do. At the beginning each label is equivalent to itself.

Comment: Thanks! the whole thing works when initializing EQ = [0,1,2,3...] and the first line of ERA.